# Using emulator as a monitor to my phone?

Tags: adb, broken-screen, external-display

The screen of my Google Pixel burned out the other day. The phone still works, but the screen doesn't turn on. Is it possible to connect to my phone via `adb` and use an emulator to see what the phone is doing (essentially, use an emulator as an external monitor)?

I can connect to the phone via `adb` and use `shell`, but what I need to do is access my Google Authenticator to get two factor authentication codes.

Answer (score 0):

Not tried this but there are possible solutions to this:

1. Using [Visor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vysor/gidgenkbbabolejbgbpnhbimgjbffefm)

   - Add Vysor as an app on Chrome.
   - Connect mobile device with USB debugging on.
   - Allow debugging on the popup that comes on the phone.
   - Vysor should then start showing the phone screen.
   - Vysor lets the user project the screen and also control the phone from the PC.
2. [Using Droid@Screen software](http://droid-at-screen.org/download.html) (requires JAVA runtime)

> Droid@Screen is a tool that will show the screen of your phone, once
>   all previous steps have been completed (i.e. drivers installed, usb
>   debugging enabled, etc).

- Download latest version of Droid@Screen here: http://droid-at-screen.org/download.html
- Set `adb` in `PATH` variables or just navigate to the platform-tools dir to start it.
- Whenever you want to project the device, **start Droid@Screen**  and plug in your device. Droid@Screen will automatically start showing the screen.
- Your computer screen can then be projected on a bigger screen using a projector.

[image]

Alternatively you can use [Aidroid](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/airdroid/hkgndiocipalkpejnpafdbdlfdjihomd?hl=en-US) or other available commercial tools such as [Wondershare MirrorGo](https://www.wondershare.com/android-mirror/)

**Acknowledgements**

- Devika, Kristen Burton: [Android Phone Screen Projection to your computer](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Android+Phone+Screen+Projection+to+your+computer#AndroidPhoneScreenProjectiontoyourcomputer-WondershareMirrorGo)